# Permissions Error installing ruby via homebrew via chef via vagrant on osx

Tags: macos, chef-infra, homebrew, vagrant

I am trying to install ruby using homebrew, using chef, run by a vagrant script in a VMWare fusion VM running mac os x 10.8.5.

During the ruby install, I get the following error:

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of brew install  ruby ----
STDOUT: ==> Installing dependencies for ruby: pkg-config, readline, libyaml, openssl
==> Installing ruby dependency: pkg-config
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/pkg-config-    0.28.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring pkg-config-0.28.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.28: 10 files, 636K
==> Installing ruby dependency: readline
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/readline-6.2.4.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring readline-6.2.4.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only: so it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

OS X provides the BSD libedit library, which shadows libreadline.
In order to prevent conflicts when programs look for libreadline we are
defaulting this GNU Readline installation to keg-only.

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4: 31 files, 1.6M
==> Installing ruby dependency: libyaml
==> Downloading http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz
STDERR: Error: Permission denied - /var/root/Library/Logs
---- End output of brew install  ruby ----
Ran brew install  ruby returned 1
```

I also got this error when I tried to install rbenv using homebrew, which failed installing autoconf.  I am not sure why it's trying to access /var/root/.  When I run "brew install autoconf" from the VM, it installs fine.

I also tried adding:

```
node.default['homebrew']['owner'] = 'vagrant'
```

to my recipe just to make sure that the homebrew install was using the local user, but it made no difference.

My recipe looks like this:

```
# required for homebrew
bash "take-usr-local-ownership" do
    user "vagrant"
    cwd "/"
    code <<-EOH
    sudo mkdir -p /usr/local
    sudo chown -R `whoami`:staff /usr/local
    EOH
end

include_recipe 'homebrew'

# Install each of the packages using the `package` resource
%w(ruby).each do |package|
   package package
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax from the chef doc looks like this:

```
package "ruby" do
  action :install
end
```

So that may be part of the issue.

The other thing is, who is homebrew installed by? Root? Vagrant? I assume you have to set that somewhere, not just who uses `brew install`.